# i cannot assign the color to face materials in blender

Tags: rendering, color

I am facing color materials everytime I tried to assign the color. When I selected the faces on the trunk of the tree and assigned the Trunk color (Brown)in edit mode, it didnt change color on trunk as shown in the first photo.

[image: this is first photo]

Moreover, I deleted the Tree color(Green) material, it has changed to trunk color on whole tree. then, I selected the faces of tree and assign Tree color, it didnt change color on materials in the second photo.
[image: second photo]

In addition, when i tried to render the layout in Cycles render engine for first photo, the trunk is appeared as green color although it was in trunk color in Eevee render engine.  Can you help me please explain this?

[image]

Comment: in the picture you show the faces are not selected, you need to select the faces, then select the slot that has the material you want to assign, and click on the Assign button. If you delete a slot, the faces that had the material get the material that is on the previous slot.

Comment: I agree with @moonboots that looking at your screenshots the most likely reason could be that you don't select the faces you want to assign the color to. Without actually assigning a material to a face correctly, all faces will have the default first material in material slot 0. Which is green in the first screenshot and brown in the second, so the tree shows exactly what I'd expect without assigning different materials to specific faces.

Comment: If you selected faces and assigned material as you mentioned ... share you simplified file with one tree to let us see, use https://blend-exchange.com ...btw in your render top tree has some trunk material faces assigned.

Comment: Thanks for comments and the photos I uploaded are the ones that deselected faces after I selected faces on trunk and clicked on assign material. I would like to show clearly that the trunk faces and tree faces are still remain unchanged

Comment: If you are sure you did everything as it's supposed to be working, then you should really upload a file for us to investigate further as @vklidu suggested.